# I encountered something weird when I rotated a object, is this a Unity bug*-*?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

As shown in the figure, there are 3 objects in the scene, namely RotatePoint, Square and Circle. Among them, RotatePoint is a black circle, square is a red rectangle, and Circle is a white circle. They form a combination, and RotatePoint is the parent object.
[image]
Next, I plan to make the entire object system rotate with the movement of the mouse, with RotatePoint as the rotation center point. So I attached this script component to RotatePoint with the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class TestRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    //For the gameobject rotatePoint
    public Transform rotatePoint;
    //For the gameobject circle :
    public Transform circle;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 MouseWorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.LogWarning("circle.pos" + circle.position);
        Vector3 direction = MouseWorldPoint - circle.position;

        float radians = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x);
        float degrees = radians * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    
        rotatePoint.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,degrees);
        Debug.DrawLine(circle.position,MouseWorldPoint,Color.red);
    }
}
```

In this code, I first convert the mouse pointer's screen coordinates to world coordinates, and then calculate its offset vector (direction) to the circle object. Set the rotation angle of the parent object RotatePoint by calculating the angle degrees of the vector direction in the world coordinate system. It seems that everything seems logical, the whole object system is centered on the RotatePoint to follow the mouse rotation, as shown in the gif:
[image]

But it's too weird. When I moved the mouse within a certain distance from the circle (white circle), something strange happened. The whole combination began to bounce and rotate. When the distance was closer, it began to rotate 360 ​​degrees continuously. As shown in the gif image：
[image]

After experimenting, I found that the above situation occurs when you calculate the overall (parent object) rotation angle based on the child object. The key is that this abnormal situation only occurs when the mouse pointer is within a certain distance from the child object(Circle), not at any time. It all happened, which made me very confused because I couldn't tell what was causing it. As mentioned above, when I change the referenced object from child (Circle)to parent(RotatePoint), everything works fine, as shown in the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    //For the gameobject rotatePoint
    public Transform rotatePoint;
    //For the gameobject circle :
    public Transform circle;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 MouseWorldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        //change from circle.position to rotatePoint.position :
        Vector3 direction = MouseWorldPoint - rotatePoint.position;
        Debug.LogWarning("circle.pos" + circle.position);

        float radians = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x);
        float degrees = radians * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    
        rotatePoint.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,degrees);
        Debug.DrawLine(circle.position,MouseWorldPoint,Color.red);
    }
}
```

The running effect is shown in the gif, and everything is normal:
[image]

This is a problem I encountered when developing a 2d shooting game, I abstracted this situation and did the above experiment separately. Looking forward to hearing from you, thank you very much.

Comment: What's the issue then? It's working fine right?

Comment: I suggest logging everything you can think of to console. At the very least, all of the variables in the project. I'm baffled why you didn't do so before.
rotatepoint, MouseWorldPoint, direction, radians, degrees.
Log everything, then reproduce the glitch. The you will see which variable is mucking up the formula. Start digging there.